# How to stop nodemon from changing port on each restart of express app?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I am new to nodejs and this is first time I am using nodemon. I am using nodejs on windows. I have got following in my `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
}
```

And I use `npm start` from command line to start my express app. The process start with a default port which is annoying. But what is even more annoying is that every time I change a file nodemon restarts the application, sometimes on an entirely different random port number. I tried changing the `script` section in `package.json` file to the below but that did not make any difference

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon ./bin/www 3000"
},
```

Comment: OK so i'm assuming you mean that it's annoying that nodemon starts on a completely different port.  That shouldn't be happening.  The point of nodemon is to give you a consistent server instance that you can connect to across file changes.  Do you have something else in your application that might be starting on the same port as node.js shortly before your nodemon instance?  If your complain is that nodemon restarts every time you change a file, then you should choose a different monitoring module, because that is the core function of nodemon...

Comment: Well, I should have worded it better. Nodemon restarting on every change is not really my complain. My complain is the use of new port on every restart. And I confirmed that no other process is using port 3000

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding your question. Let me clarify. So, your server is listening to a different port everytime it restarts (regardless the restart is triggered by nodemon or others)?

Comment: @NoobCoder the restart is only triggered by nodemon and it is changing ports on every restart

Comment: What if you restart manually without nodemon? Does the port changes? I'm just trying to narrow down the cause

Comment: If I do not use nodemon ,then I can use node environment variable to start the express app on port 3000 all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems you're specifying the port through an env variable, let's call it EXPRESS_PORT. The node process doesn't inherit it when you start it with npm because `npm start` creates a new shell with its own environment. So you end up passing port `undefined` to express. That makes it bind to a random free port. To fix this you can set the variable in the start command:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "EXPRESS_PORT=3000 nodemon ./bin/www"
}
```

Or you can export it from your shell with `export EXPRESS_PORT=3000` and then run `npm start`. If you do this you need to make sure to always export before starting the server, so you might want to place the export in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.